# How can I resolve a Google Maps API key Issue?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have been having trouble with the Google Maps API for one week now and I'm unable to resolve it :(

I have a site that has been using the Google Maps v3 for several weeks now without any issues. But suddenly, it starts complaining that: Google has deactivated the use of the Google Maps API for this application, because the offered key is not a valid Google-API-Key or the use of Google Maps v3 is not allowed for this site.

I double checked everything, including: trying a new key; checking domain restrictions and activation in the API-console - Everything is alright.

I'm using simple authentication. Every help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you running a development/live version of the site? There may be some issues for local development when using HOSTS file to create the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Version Handling Has Changed. This Code Is No Longer Valid (see the code below in the update):

One thing you can do immediately to bypass such problems: explicitly set the version of the API you are using to **3.6**:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&sensor=false">
</script>
```

Keys were introduced in *3.7*, so you do not get any warnings if you set your version to: *3.6*.

### Important Update That Makes the JavaScript Code Above Invalid:

Setting the version to *3.6* will no longer function as a work-around for this, because you are no longer able to request version *3.6*. You should *not* use the code above, but should use the following code to load the Google Maps JavaScript *3.8* library:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.8&sensor=false">
</script>
```

Google recently announced a version update; here is the content of the Google announcement email:

> We recently released a new minor version of the Google Maps API. This
>   means that the versions are now:
>   3.9: Development/Nightly
>   3.8: Feature Stable
>   3.7: Frozen
>
> **3.6 has been removed: if you request it you will receive 3.7.**
>
> In this latest release of 3.9, we've added:
>   * Country restriction for Autocomplete (AutocompleteOptions?.componentRestrictions)
>   * Regions and Cities type filters
>
> You will also get all the features of 3.8 (now Feature Stable),
>   including:
>
> - WeatherLayer and CloudLayer
> - Click-to-go/Click-to-zoom in Street View
> - orderBy, limit and offset for FusionTablesLayer
> - utc_offset and opening_hours in PlaceResult
> - google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation() and isLocationOnEdge()
> - DemographicsLayer (Maps for Business only)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. As you already expect: The workaround worked fine - until now :( Do you have any other suggestions how to continue?

Comment: hmm...ok I just excluded the API key completely from the call (so the only GET parameter left is sensor=false) and then it worked (?). Its not quite clear to me, because it also did before _with_ the key included...but - nevermind :) Thanks for your help

Comment: I've updated my original answer to add clarification about the licensing changes.